# positioning absolute element to the rigth:0 of document

Tags: html, css, positioning

i have menu/submenu element in my page
 which is something like

```
<div class="category">
  <div class="subcategory"></div>
</div>
<div class="category">
  <div class="subcategory"></div>
</div>
<div class="category">
  <div class="subcategory"></div>
</div>
<style>
.category { position:relative}
.subcateory { position:absolute   ; top: 40px ; right: 0px ; width: 100vw}
</style>
```

it looks something like 
[image]

what i want is for submenues to cover %100 of document and to start from right:0 of document something like 
[image]

i've manageed to set the width to 100% of document by 100vw but im stock on how to set the right position so it strats from 0 point of document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.category { background: red; height: 50px; width:25%; display: inline-block; }
.subcategory { position:absolute; top: 60px; right:0px; width:100%; background:blue;height: 100px; }
```

```html
<div class="category">
  <div class="subcategory"></div>
</div>
<div class="category">
  <div class="subcategory"></div>
</div>
<div class="category">
  <div class="subcategory"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanx , am i missing something here ? when i set `subcateory` style to  width:100%; right:0 ... i get 100% and `right:0`of its parent`(.category)`  not the documnt

Comment: I believe that you are missing the fact that you have to remove the `.category { position: relative }` from your parent category as seen in the demo.